# MySQL query with alias not using an index

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

The following query is showing up in my log as not using an index:

```
SELECT ordinal,YEAR(ceremonydate) as yr 
FROM awardinfo 
ORDER BY YEAR(ceremonydate) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Explain shows it's not using an index:

```
id: 1
select_type:    SIMPLE
table: awardinfo
type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
key: NULL
key_len: NULL
ref: NULL
rows: 72
Extra: Using filesort
```

ordinal, ceremonydate both have an index. Are they not being used due to the yr alias? Is there a way to create an index on YEAR(ceremonydate) instead of just ceremonydate? Or is there a way to index an alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the alias. `ORDER BY` can use an index if it is ordering by something that is indexed. While `ceremonyDate` date may be indexed, `YEAR(ceremoneyDate)` changes the value of `ceremonyDate` to something completely different, so `YEAR(ceremoneyDate)` is not indexed.

And since you can't index an alias, this means that in order for an `ORDER BY` to use an index, it must be a simple column name, or list of column names.

You should be able to do this and use the index:

```
SELECT ordinal,YEAR(ceremonydate) as yr 
FROM awardinfo 
ORDER BY ceremonydate DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Without knowing what your data looks like, that may work for you instead.

More info:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can test this by running a simple select query and using the alias:
`SELECT ordinal, ceremonydate as yr FROM ...` and start adding complexity to your query to see where the indexes stop being used.  Most likely, because you are ordering based on `YEAR(ceremonydate)` mysql is creating a temporary table.  Your best bet is to process ceremonydate in your code.  MySQL loses a lot of efficiency with inline processing and computation like `YEAR()` because it has to create those temporary tables.