# MySQL query is taking too much time

Tags: mysql

I have query below:

```
SELECT t.t_id
     , t.usr_idx
     , t.t_is_for
     , t.tg_ids
     , t.created_time
     , t.allow_reply
     , u.usr_name
     , u.usr_avatar
     , u.show_profile
     , IF(u.usr_timeline != '',CONCAT('https://s3.amazonaws.com/tuurnts3thumbnail/',u.usr_timeline),'') as usr_timeline
     , u.node_userid
     , t.t_time
  FROM tuu_tuurnt t
  JOIN tuu_user u 
    ON t.usr_idx = u.usr_idx 
   AND u.usr_state = 1
  LEFT 
  JOIN tuu_post p 
    ON t.t_id = p.t_id 
   AND p.usr_idx = 44756
  LEFT 
  JOIN tuu_friend f 
    ON f.frd_my_idx = 44756
   AND f.frd_your_idx = t.usr_idx
  LEFT 
  JOIN tuu_friend fl 
    ON fl.frd_your_idx = 44756 
   AND fl.frd_my_idx = t.usr_idx
 WHERE t.status = 0
   AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT b.tuu_b_by_usr_idx 
                      FROM tuu_blocked as b 
                     WHERE b.tuu_b_usr_idx = 44756
                       AND t.usr_idx = b.tuu_b_by_usr_idx
                  )     
 GROUP 
    BY t.t_id     
 ORDER 
    BY t.t_time DESC
     , t.t_id DESC     
 LIMIT 0,30;
```

It takes almost 7-8 second to give result but when I remove order by t.t_time and t.t_id then it runs within 1 sec max.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Put some effort into formatting your query.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, inclusion of a GROUP BY clause is generally a sure sign that you have no idea what you're doing. What are you doing? In order to answer, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Please, add `EXPLAIN` result to your question. It will indicates the index that MySQL actually decided to use for ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Without an index, MySQL must begin with the first row and then read through the entire table to find the relevant rows. The larger the table, the more this costs. See [How MySQL Uses Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html) for details.  See also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872277/mysql-query-with-alias-not-using-an-index) about using indexes and aliases together.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you see order by t_time which is taking time. and this is indexed already. if i take out order by works within a sec only.